# In Visual Basic how do you gain access other windows!

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to use a program to automatically search forum posts to check for certain misspelled words. I'm using the findstr method but cannot get it to search the textbox in the browser.

I do know how to have it search within the application itself by using textbox1.text for example but not other windows.

Comment: VB or VB.NET? I assume VB.NET.

Answer (score -1):

Just try this out where myOtherForm is the name of the form you want to access the textBox:

```
dim otherFrm as myOtherForm1
```

with otherFrm

```
If textBox1.text = "MySearch" then
    .../... Do something
End if
```

End With

Comment: This won't do, the asker wants to read text from a web browser, not just another form of the same executable.